# How to change the LookAndFeel of the NetBeans Platform Framework Application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, look-and-feel, netbeans-platform

I cannot figure out how to change the LookAndFeel of the application I built on the NetBeans platform framework, can anybody please help? I want to change its look using the TinyLAF java api http://www.muntjak.de/hans/java/tinylaf/index.html. I know how to change the LookAndFeel when developing a regular Swing application in the NetBeans IDE, but not when developing it on the NetBeans Platform framework.

This is the code, for TinyLAF, that I use for regular Swing applications:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout(true);
System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("de.muntjak.tinylookandfeel.TinyLookAndFeel");
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

TinyLaF looks for a default theme file named 'Default.theme' (case-sensitive). If it finds one, this file will be loaded at startup. 
(The 'Default.theme' file is an ordinary TinyLaF .theme file, just with a special name, you can take any .theme file and rename it to 'Default.theme').

TinyLaF will search the following URLs:

1. TinyLookAndFeel.class.getResource("/Default.theme");

   - finds 'Default.theme' if it is inside tinylaf.jar
2. Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("Default.theme");

   - finds 'Default.theme' if it is inside your application's JAR
3. new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Default.theme").toURI().toURL();

   - finds 'Default.theme' if it is inside the home directory
4. new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "Default.theme").toURI().toURL();

   - finds 'Default.theme' if it is inside the working directory

**Please note that my question is not how to change the LookAndFeel of the NetBeans IDE,  but how to do it for the Java Application built on top of NetBeans Platform framework.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following searching the net: you need to do it in the module "Installer".
check this link for where you need to add: http://joshiegeek.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/netbeans-platform-custom-laf.html

this one has actual code sample (please ignore the title :)) : http://forums.netbeans.org/topic39450.html

and finally this one talks of a specific plaf but has few comments along the way : https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/blue_look_and_feel_for

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution is in the first link.

Comment: That first link is dead. I wish you had told a bit more about what it used to say...

Comment: @Christopher Bruns I post link in order not to bring the whole content. anyway, searching again I found this: http://devblog.virtage.com/2011/09/how-to-change-look-feel-of-netbeans-ide-and-application/     check the section "NetBeans Platform apps" the solution is one line. I don't know how it compares to the other way but I hope this will help in your case.

Comment: @A.J. I'm sorry but the first link you posted and the one you posted in comment both can't be open from here. :(

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can change the look and feel of Swing very easily as its based on **MVC architecture**.

**2.** Swing is also known as `PLAF` **(Pluggable Look And Feel)**, so **keep the same Model part and change the View**, example like same model for desktop and web application.

**3.** Use

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Your_Choice_of_Look_and_Feel);  // To set the Look and Feel
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);        // To refresh the JFrame and Components
```

**See this for more details:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Comment: The OP already knows this I guess as he mentioned the code he uses for regular swing applications. He wants to know how to do it for an application running on Netbeans Platform.

Comment: He need to manually change it in the GUI code, as i mentioned above... And i hope he is using GroupLayout which netbeans team developed in 2005. that would make arranging the component much easier

Answer (score 0):

Had to find that first link mentioned in an earlier post on the waybackmachine ...

Answer is to add a runtime argument or put it in the project.properties file. The line to add (for e.g. Metal) is

```
run.args.extra=--laf javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
```