# How to change LookAndFeel in my NetBeans RCP application if it is written in pure JavaFX?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, rcp, look-and-feel

I found there is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637006/how-to-change-the-lookandfeel-of-the-netbeans-platform-framework-application) teaching you how to change the LAF of the NetBeans Platform Framework Application. However I don't know how to make it if our application's UI is completely rendered in JavaFX. AFAIK, NetBeans is built in swing, so I'm also wondering, whether the change on LAF only affect the outside window frame and won't affect the part rendered in JavaFX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaFX have a "native look and feel" option like Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968409/does-javafx-have-a-native-look-and-feel-option-like-swing)

Comment: @TomN possibly I didn't explain my question well, actually what I want to know is whether the change of LAF of my NetBeans RCP application through the way the link I post above will affect the UI part rendered in JavaFX. However, according to the question link you post, it seems, they are rendered separately. Am I understanding it correctly?